# Finite dimensional quotient $\Rightarrow$ closedness?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $V\subset X$ a subspace. Suppose that the quotient space $X/V$ is finite dimensional. Is $V$ then closed?

In other words: if $V$ is not closed, then can $X/V$ be finite dimensional?

(I think the answer is NO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be the kernel of a discontinuous linear functional $f$. Then $X/V$ is one-dimensional but $V$ isn't closed (open mapping theorem).